# CORS issue when making GET requests to Django server behind Caddy reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, python, django, cors, caddy

I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when making GET requests to my Django server, which is hosted behind a Caddy reverse proxy. Here's the situation:

1. I have a Django server running, serving an API.
2. The Django server is behind a Caddy reverse proxy.
3. I'm trying to make GET requests to my Django API from a front-end application hosted at a different domain. Using JS And Ajax requests

I have already tried the following:

1. Enabled the django-cors-headers package and added it to my INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE settings in the correct order.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',  # Added this app
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  # Placed CorsMiddleware here
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Configured CORS settings in my Django project's settings.py.

```py
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'GET',
    'POST',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"https://www.example.net",
"http://localhost:5000",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000",
"http://127.0.0.1:5501"
]
```

Despite these configurations, I'm still encountering a CORS-related error when making GET requests to my Django API.

Here's the error message:

```cs
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.example.net/nodeData/?nid=13. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
```

To add more context the return method on the django server looks like this:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def get_vertex_data(request):
    try:
        # get the search item
        id = request.GET.get('nid', '')
        # search for the item in the db
        graphdb = GDM.get_graph_database()
        vertices = graphdb['vertices']
        vertRaw = vertices.find_one({'id':int(id)})
        vertRaw.pop("_id", None)
        
        response = JsonResponse(vertRaw, safe=False)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponse("Something broke sorry")
```

I've checked my Caddy configuration, and it seems to be correctly forwarding requests to my Django server.I can curl and get data from this server on my command prompt. But whenever I fetch data like so:

```js
async function getVertex() {
    const rawData = await fetch("https://www.example.net/nodeData/?nid=13", {
        method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc., // Set the request mode to 'no-cors'
    });
    console.log(rawData)
    const JSONData = await rawData.json();
    console.log(JSONData)
    return JSONData;
}
```

It keeps throwing a coors error (The one mentioned above) on my browser. Where am I going wrong? Any insights or suggestions on resolving this CORS issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` should be listed first in your `MIDDLEWARE` list, before any security/auth middleware, since preflight requests are not authenticated.

Comment: Changed that and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What I suggested in my earlier comment is a necessary (but not a sufficient) condition for things to work. You've still made some progress. Let me think about what you can do next to resolve the issue.

Comment: What is the [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) of your client?

Comment: localhost:5505/ like where I am trying to debug this from.

Comment: But... `http://localhost:5505` is not listed as an allowed origin in your CORS configuration...

Comment: I though it was because I was declaring the cors sites after I had declared that all origins are allowed and removed that block of code and I still got the same error

Comment: Sorry I meant 5501

Comment: Even so, `http://localhost:5501` is not listed as an allowed origin in your CORS configuration. I don't know whether it's clear to you, but `http://127.0.0.1:5501` and `http://localhost:5501` are distinct Web origins. Allowing `http://127.0.0.1:5501` doesn't mean allowing `http://localhost:5501`, and vice versa.

Comment: You should also drop `response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"`. If you use an established CORS middleware (as you should), don't also manually set CORS response headers in your code.

Comment: Okay I tested it right now from http://127.0.0.1:5501 And it still fails. Thanks for the pointer on the response CORS header

Comment: At this stage, I suggest editing your question and adding screenshots of your browser's Network tab clearly showing the request headers and response headers.